# Use Spring Data JPA to Find By Column from 1 table and order by column from another table

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, crud

I am trying to return data from 2 different tables using `WorkoutCaseId` from `ReportedWorkout` and sort them using `PaymentDate` from `Payment`.

**ReportedWorkout**

```
+-------------------+----------------+
| ReportedWorkoutId | WorkoutCaseId  |
+-------------------+----------------+
```

**Payment**

```
+-----------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+
| PaymentId | ReportedWorkoutId  | PaymentDate  | PaymentAmount |
+-----------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want to return data as:

```
SELECT * FROM ReportedWorkout
JOIN table2 ON ReportedWorkout.ReportedWorkoutId = Payment.ReportedWorkoutId
WHERE WorkoutCaseId = '123'
ORDER BY PaymentDate DESC

@Entity
@Table(name = "ReportedWorkout")
public class ReportedWorkoutEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ReportedWorkoutId")
    private Long reportedWorkoutId;

    @Column(name = "WorkoutCaseId")
    private String workoutCaseId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "ReportedWorkout")
    private Set<PaymentEntity> payments = new LinkedHashSet<>();

...
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "Payment")
public class PaymentEntity extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PaymentId" , nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long paymentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ReportedWorkoutId")
    private ReportedWorkoutEntity reportedWorkout;

    @Column(name = "PaymentAmount")
    private BigDecimal paymentAmount;

    @Column(name = "PaymentDate" , nullable = false)
    private LocalDate paymentDate;
...
}
```

I got it to return data by `WorkoutCaseId`:

```
@Repository
public interface ReportedWorkoutRepository extends CrudRepository<ReportedWorkoutEntity, Long> {    
    ReportedWorkoutEntity findByWorkoutCaseId(String workoutCaseId);
}
```

But I don't know how to order it by PaymentDate?

```
findByWorkoutCaseIdOrderByPaymentDateDesc
```

I get following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property paymentDate found for type ReportedWorkoutEntity!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since paymentDate is not a property of ReportedWorkoutEntity the error makes sense.  For the repository method use the fully qualified name for paymentDate relative to ReportedWorkoutEntity.

So: findByWorkoutCaseIdOrderBy**Payments**PaymentDateDesc

Comment: For some reason PersistentSet doesn't preserve order :(
I made sure that it's LinkedHashSet, but it still doesn't work: private Set<PaymentEntity> payments = new LinkedHashSet<>()

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use another entity, you have to mentioned it in your method signature which you defined in @Repository interface.

As mentioned by @churd, you have to create the method signature with that format only.

There is another option like mentioned @Query on top of method and define sql in it which you want to execute.